# RegEx for matching \n and space

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use RegEx within my Perl script to parse a file to match: Space and `\n` (newline) in an alternating manner:

First I would like it to match space then a `\n`, then a space (which is on a new line in the file... and so on).

Comment: Seriously?  You tried posting a regex question in the "Wild Wild West" of Q and A? 8o0 Wow...I'm kind of surprised you didn't get some answers about telling you to just do it on a mac/linux/pc...yes, I know perl works on them all and it's platform independant; that's kind of my point ;0))))

Comment: That is an odd parsing problem. Can you describe not the steps you think you need, but the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(^ \n)+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
if($file =~/ |(?: \n)+ ?/) {
        print $file." has the pattern\n";
}
```

The regex used is `|(?: \n)+ ?` which matches:

- Single space or
- One or more `space\n` followed by an
  optional `space`

Answer (score 0):

To match the Start of a line, use caret `^`.

To match the space, you can use a literal space, or for any whitespace, use `\s`.

Putting `sgm` at the end of the pattern, e.g. `/pattern/sgm` will cause it to match across lines.

There is more info and some examples at [perldoc perlfaq6](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted the second space in your pattern to be on the new line. Now whether you'll be able to get this depends on where you got your string from (well, maybe not *where*, but I guess you get my point). If the data you're parsing is read from a file, then you must read the file in paragraph mode (i.e. each paragraph instead of each line will constitute a record).

Assuming you are using the file handle FILE, do this:

```
{
   local $/ = ""; # one paragraph constitutes one record
   while (<FILE>) {
      if (/ \n /) {
         print "Found one match!\n";
      }
   }
}
```

Please note that the regex pattern I have used does not take into account multiple occurrences of space-newline-space, as I wasn't sure what exactly you were trying to do. But anyway, my main point is the use of

```
local $/ = "";
```

HTH